# Find a single approximating boundary for multiple objects in binary image

Tags: c++, opencv

An example case of the image is given below. I use the binary version of the image for further processing. I would like to get the contour of the object to perform shape matching. I have written a code that returns the boundary contour given a binary image. However, the problem arises when the image does not contain one single object as is the case here, You can see the lower portion of the leg even a palm is not attached to the body. I am interested in finding the contour approximating the entire object. So, far opencv has not helped.

[image]

My get contour function is using opencvblobslib library and looks like this. Basically it detects all the blobs and filters out really small blobs. Then, it checks to see if there is only one contour left. This works as long as the objects are connected, but I would like to make it robust so that it can handle the multiple object case as well.

```
vector<Point>  getContour(Mat binaryImg) {
    CBlobResult res(binaryImg, Mat(),NUMCORES);  // We get all possible bounding box using this object
    CBlobResult resFiltered;                     // We shall then filter the bboxes if their area is less
                                                 // than alpha % of the total area

    double originalImageArea = binaryImg.rows * binaryImg.cols;
    double alpha = 0.05;
    double lowerLimitRectArea = alpha * originalImageArea;
    double bbox_area;
    for(int i = 0; i < res.GetNumBlobs(); i++){
        CBlob* b = res.GetBlob(i);
        Rect bbox = b->GetBoundingBox();
        double bbox_area = bbox.area();
        if(bbox_area < lowerLimitRectArea){
            b->to_be_deleted = 1.0;
        }
    }

    res.Filter(resFiltered, B_EXCLUDE, CBlobGetTBDeleted(), B_EQUAL, 1.0,1.0);

    if (resFiltered.GetNumBlobs() > 1) {
        cout << " Errror case " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    CBlob* b = resFiltered.GetBlob(0);
    CBlobContour* extCont = b->GetExternalContour();
    t_PointList contPts = extCont->GetContourPoints();
    vector<Point> contour;
    contour.resize(contPts.size());

    for( int i=0; i < contPts.size(); i++) {
        contour[i] = cv::Point(contPts[i].x, contPts[i].y);
    }
    return contour;
}
```

Comment: I solved the issue by dilating the image by sufficiently large structuring element.

Comment: you can post it as an answer if you have a solution